# kube-stat-metrics is not working when only master node is running in a cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kube-state-metrics

I am monitoring Kubernetes cluster ( which is deployed using kubeadm ) with grafana and Prometheus.

I am facing some difficulty with kube-state-metrics that is when I up the only master node then I am seeing kube-state-metrics down in Prometheus targets but when I up the one node then kube-state-metrics is up in Prometheus target.

Another interesting part here is when I up only master node I see one kube-state-meterics pod is up and running in kube-system namespace but I am unable to access the metrics.

Am I missing anything in understanding kube-state-metrics?

Please help me out.

Comment: logs from kube state metrics pod?

Comment: Additionally please include in your post information like Kubernetes cluster version, operating system of your master and node machines. Is your infrastructure in cloud or is it bare metal? Is the cluster working properly? How did you install Prometheus?